# Is it possible to have subprojects define their own dependencies?

Tags: scala, build, sbt, playframework-2.3, subproject

Using SBT 0.13.5 (and Play framework 2.3.x), is it possible to have a subproject define its own dependencies (and plugins) so that the root project need not be concerned?

What I'm looking for is a convenient way to modularise a bigger project into core components that can be reused and deployed by their own. This blogpost[1] describes a configuration for play 2.2.2 but I have not been so fortunate with more recent (2.3.x) builds, I imagine due to changes in the build procedure.

[1] http://blog.protegra.com/2014/01/17/scala-sbt-intellij-play-project-as-child-project/

Comment: Yes, [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html#sbt+is+recursive).

Comment: This doesn't help I'm afraid; what you're linking to explicitly talks about the project/ folder and how the build definition is recursive in nature, ie it can have its own build definition.

The project folder of subprojects is ignored from what I've seen, which spurred the question into existence. This makes it cumbersome to, as an example, have a Play! subproject, as the root project needs to pull out its plugins definition for the build to work at all.